# Trying to make hidden div fade in on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm looking for some help with fading hidden div's in.
This is what I have so far, but it doesn't seem to want to work, the div just appears with no fade.

```
$("div").hide();
          // Show chosen div, and hide all others
        $("a").click(function (e) 
        {
            //e.preventDefault();
            $("#" + $(this).attr("class")).show().siblings('div').hide();
        });

$('.one').click(function(){
    $("#one").fadeIn("5000");
    });
```

html

```
<body>
<a href="#" class="one">One</a>
<a href="#" class="two">Two</a>
<a href="#" class="three">Three</a>
<a href="#" class="four">Four</a><br /><br />
<div id="one">One</div>
<div id="two">Two</div>
<div id="three">Three</div>
<div id="four">Four</div><br/><br/>
</body>
```

Comment: share your HTML part also.

Comment: create a fiddle for this

Comment: `.one` is also an anchor, and the first click function shows the element before the second one is able to fade it in. Also, when passing numbers to `fadeIn`, use numbers, not strings.

Comment: It looks like you're using a class and ID named 'one'? Are you sure you've got the selectors correct? Maybe change one of them so it's a little easier to code?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/2so7e1re/

Comment: Remove the `show()` from your code. That is what instantly shows the div.

Answer (score 2):

Just click event on `a`like this:

```
    $("div").hide();
      // Show chosen div, and hide all others
    $("a").click(function (e) {
        //e.preventDefault();
        $("#" + $(this).attr("class")).fadeIn(5000).siblings('div').hide();
    });
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AmanVirdi/1bhyLx6u/)

Answer (score 0):

```js
setTimeout(function() {

 $("#one").css('display','none');

}, 5000);
```

Comment: This doesn't really "fade-in" so much as "disappear." (So pretty much the opposite of what's being asked.)

Answer (score 0):

you don't see the change because "One" is staying on the same position. Try to hide it first, then you can fadeIn

```
$('.one').click(function(){
    $("#one").hide().fadeIn("5000");
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
$("body").on('click', '#button-hide' function(e){
    $("#" + $(this).attr("class")).show().siblings('div').hide();
})

$("body").on('click', '#button-show' function(e){
    $("#one").fadeIn("5000");
})
```

For best answers, please explain more detail you problem. Include the context and example.
Salute!